# Not able to add cluster in opscenter getting error unable to connect to cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

I am trying to create a datastax cluster with datastax enterprise. I have changed Cassandra.yaml of the node and started Cassandra and opscenter on the node.

I am able to connect to opscenter via webbroser. But when I am trying to do "Add Cluster" and put that particular host IP, it shows error message saying ***"Error creating cluster: Unable to connect to cluster"***

I could see below text in opscenter log

```
**2013-10-29 16:44:21-0700 []  INFO: Mem Info: 96586MB
2013-10-29 16:44:24-0700 [] DEBUG: EC2 Instance type: None
2013-10-29 16:44:27-0700 [] DEBUG: EC2 Instance ami: None
2013-10-29 16:44:27-0700 []  INFO: Package Manager: Unknown
2013-10-29 16:45:21-0700 [] DEBUG: Average opscenterd CPU usage: 0.46%, memory usage: 38 MB
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 [] DEBUG: Trying to connect to node 10.182.160.4 over thrift
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 [] DEBUG: Not returning SASL credentials for 10.182.160.4
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x2b775f0>
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 []  INFO: <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x2b7e830> will retry in 2 seconds
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 [] DEBUG: Problem while pinging node: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/ThriftService.py", line 157, in checkThriftConnection
        UserError: User aborted connection: Shutdown requested.
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 []  WARN: ProcessingError while calling CreateClusterConfController: Unable to connect to cluster
2013-10-29 16:45:37-0700 []  INFO: Stopping factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x2b775f0>**
```

Can anybody please help me fixing this?

Jenish

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to provide more information. Did you set 'rpc_address' in cassandra.yaml? Is that the same ip you are specifying in the OpsCenter add cluster form? Can you connect to the Cassandra instance with cqlsh or cassandra-cli?

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: Im also curious cause I have similar issue.